# FluentNHibernate está montando a consulta errada

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate

**Prezados,**

Após fazer o mapeamento das tabelas, fiz a consulta a uma delas para então retornar a informação "filha". O sql foi montado corretamente, contudo o nome da coluna chave (PK) foi alterado o que fez acontecer um erro na execução do script. O script está correto, mas o nome da coluna pk da tabela pessoa foi escrita errada. Vejam:

**CONSULTA**

```
var partePessoas = (from pdoc in Sessao.Query<PessoaDocumento>()
                    let documento = pdoc.NumDocPess.Trim()
                    where documento.Equals(numDocumento)
                    select pdoc.Pessoa.Parte).ToList().Distinct();
```

**Script montado:**

```
select parte2_.CodParte     as col_0_0_,
       parte2_.CodParte     as col_1_0_,
       pessoadocu0_.CodPess as col_2_0_,
       parte2_.CodParte     as Cod1_1974_,
       parte2_.ClassId      as Cla2_1974_,
       parte2_.CodDoc       as Cod3_1974_,
       parte2_.CodPess      as Cod4_1974_,
       parte2_.NumOrd       as Num5_1974_,
       parte2_.Pessoa_id    as Pes6_1974_
  from PESSOADOCUMENTO pessoadocu0_
  left outer join PESSOA pessoa1_ on pessoadocu0_.Pessoa_id = pessoa1_.CodPess
  left outer join PARTE parte2_ on pessoa1_.CodPess = parte2_.Pessoa_id
where trim(both from(RetiraMascaraCpfCnpj(pessoadocu0_.NumDocPess))) = '00000000000'
```

Contudo, onde aparece 'parte2_.Pessoa_id' deveria ser 'parte2_.CodPess', conforme o mapeamento abaixo:

**MAPEAMENTO PESSOA**

```
namespace Modelo.Mapas.Esparta
{
    public class PessoaMapa : ClassMap<Pessoa>
    {
        public PessoaMapa()
        {
            Table("PESSOA");
            Id(u => u.CodPess).Column("CodPess");
            Map(u => u.ClassId);
            Map(u => u.CodTipPerso);
            Map(u => u.IndAtivo).CustomType<Util.ActiveBoolType>();
            Map(u => u.Nome);
            Map(u => u.NomeFon);
            Map(u => u.NomeMai);
            HasMany(x => x.Documento);
            HasMany(x => x.Parte);
            HasMany(x => x.Advogado);                
        }
    }
}
```

**MAPEAMENTO DE PESSOADOCUMENTO**

```
namespace Modelo.Mapas.Esparta
{
    public class PessoaDocumentoMapa : ClassMap<PessoaDocumento>
    {
        public PessoaDocumentoMapa()
        {
            Table("PESSOADOCUMENTO");
            Id(p => p.CodPess);
            Map(p => p.CodPessDoc);
            Map(p => p.CodTipDocPess);
            Map(p => p.NumDocPess).Formula("(Esparta2.RetiraMascaraCpfCnpj(NumDocPess))");
            Map(p => p.Cpf).Formula("(Decode(CodTipDocPess, 1, Esparta2.RetiraMascaraCpfCnpj(NumDocPess), ''))");
            Map(p => p.Cnpj).Formula("(Decode(CodTipDocPess, 2, Esparta2.RetiraMascaraCpfCnpj(NumDocPess), ''))");
            References(p => p.Pessoa);
        }
    }
}
```

**MAPEAMENTO DE PARTE**

```
namespace Modelo.Mapas
{
    public class ParteMapa : ClassMap<Parte>
    {
        public ParteMapa()
        {
            Table("PARTE");
            Id(u => u.CodParte);
            Map(u => u.ClassId);
            Map(u => u.CodDoc);
            Map(u => u.CodPess);
            Map(u => u.NumOrd);
            HasMany(u => u.ParteProcesso);
            References(u => u.Pessoa);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "onde aparece 'parte2_.Pessoa_id' deveria ser 'parte2_.CodPess'"; Edite a pergunta e inclua por favor o mapeamento da "parte2" (no caso, tabela `PARTE`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após pesquisa, descobrir que é preciso especificar o nome da coluna no mapeamento, assim:

```
public PessoaMapa()
{
   Table("PESSOA");
   (...)
   HasMany(x => x.Documentos).KeyColumn("CodPess");
   HasMany(x => x.Partes).KeyColumn("CodPess"); 
   HasMany(x => x.Advogados).KeyColumn("CodPess");
 }
```

E assim:

```
public PessoaDocumentoMapa()
        {
            Table("ESPARTA2.PESSOADOCUMENTO");
            (...)
            References(p => p.Pessoa, "CodPess").ForeignKey("CodPess");
        }
```

Desta forma a consulta foi construída corretamente!